# CSS rule overwritten by media queries for larger devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a website where I have an element `.mainContent` and want it to have a different width for different devices. For smaller devices I want it to have the width of 800px and on desktop devices I want it to have the width of 1296px. Below are my CSS rules. The problem is that the last media query rule is overwriting the first rule and so the width for the desktop devices is always 800px and I don't knoq why. I did as [w3school tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) says but it doesn't work.

```
.mainContent {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: 65px;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  .mainContent {
    width: 1296px;
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mainContent">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And it works as intended, just tried it

Comment: @SagarV no, made a typoo here. The screen size should over 1300px.

Comment: @CarlBinalla When I toggle device toolbar in Chrome and pick Galaxy S5 that has a width of 360px the element gets the width of 1296px so the media query is overwriting the main rule. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a snippet?

Comment: Indeed, it works here https://jsfiddle.net/jedrekd/mdL9u4z6/ but it doesn't work on my local computer. The width is always 1296px;

Comment: Did you add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in head tag?

Comment: @jedi Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere ion your original CSS? Try copying the original to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you not added viewport then add this viewport and it's working fine:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

If after adding viewport it's not working then Please try below code:

```
    .mainContent {
        margin-right: 65px;
        float: right;
    }



    @media only screen and (min-width:1300px) {
        .mainContent {
            width: 1296px;
        }

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width:320px) {
        .mainContent {
            width: 800px;
        }

    }
```

Please review this link for understand the flow of adjust media queries: ( https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/ )